# Visual Basic Append to a specific point in a text file

Tags: vb.net, string-matching

I am currently trying to manipulate a line in a file that we are using to retain data, using comma delimiters. For example -

```
121,1212, XJAY,Sean K,Kean S,AAAA-BBBB-AAAA-BBBB-AAAA
12456,987654,WYST,Steve Jobs,Bill Gates,CAAA-BBBB-AAAA-BBBB-AAAA
```

If I assume that the last line is always a unique code, is it possible to identify that line in the text file and append it with another field?

Prior research has been reading through the APIs for `StreamReader` and `StreamWriter`, and looking through other StackOverflow questions, however most questions seem focused on just appending to the end of the file, or in different languages!

As always thank you for your time, and if there is anything I've left off please let me know!

Comment: Its not clear what you want to do exactly ... the general approach is to load everything into memory, manipulate, write back.

Comment: I guess I'm trying to ask if there's a way to write back without writing the entire memory buffer back into the file, as the text file is several thousand lines and I assumed that would be too much to load everything, find the specific line, manipulate, then rewrite back. If I'm wrong, then excellent! Otherwise, the task of converting to an actual database begins...

Comment: What you're trying to do is random access, which VB supports, but only in fixed length blocks and not variable length lines like you want.  The best method is like Alex K said, load it all in memory, change and write back. The only other alternative is to read lines one at a time, change the lines you want and then write them back to a temp file, one at a time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't manipulate a line in a file in any reasonably easy way.

There are no methods to work with lines in a file, because files are not line based. They are not even character based. The bytes in the file are decoded into characters, then the line break characters are recognised and the characters can be split into lines.

The easiest way to manipulate a line is to read the entire file into a string array, change the string that you want change, then write the entire string array to the file.

Example:

```
Dim fileName As String = "c:\data.txt"
Dim lines As String() = File.ReadAllLines(fileName)
For i As Integer = 0 To lines.Length - 1
  Dim line As String = lines(i)
  If line.StartsWith("12456,") Then
    lines(i) = line & ",More data"
  End If
Next
File.WriteAllLines(fileName, lines)
```

Comment: Always unfortunate when the answer to a question is "You can't". But seriously, thanks for the further explanation and code example, will give this a try.

Comment: I think the last code line should be File.WriteAllLines(filename, lines)

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a way to parse Each line with StreamReader and StreamWriter: Here it is:

```
            'You will need Imports System.IO
            Dim TheNewFile As String
            Dim MyLine As String
            Dim MyStream2 As New FileStream("C:\Your Directory\YourFile.txt", FileMode.Open)
            Dim MyReader As New StreamReader(MyStream2)
            Dim MySettings As New StringReader(MyReader.ReadToEnd)
            MyReader.BaseStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin)
            MyReader.Close()
            MyStream2.Close()
            Try
                Do
                    MyLine = MySettings.ReadLine
                    'This if statement is an exit parameter. It can be if it contains or if 5 consecutive lines are nothing. It could be a number of things
                    If MyLine Is Nothing Then Exit Do
                    'This is the file you will write. You could do if MyLine = "Test" Then ........... append whatever and however you need to
                    TheNewFile = TheNewFile & MyLine & vbCrLf

                Loop
            Catch ex As Exception
                MsgBox(ex.ToString())
            End Try
            '-----------------Write The new file!!!----------------
            Dim MyStream3 As New FileStream("C:\Where you want to write New File\NewFileName.txt", FileMode.Create)
            Dim MyWriter3 As New StreamWriter(MyStream3)
            MyWriter3.Write(TheNewFile & "Test")
            MyWriter3.Close()
            MyStream3.Close()
```